# big o notation of fraction $\frac{\log(N+1)}{\log(N)}$

Tags: asymptotics

I want to estimate big-O notation for $\frac{\log(8n^2)}{\log(n)}$.

I think the big-O notation is constant. am I right?

in case of $\frac{\log(N+1)}{\log(N)}$, is it the same and O(1)?

and what about $\frac{\log(N^3+7n+1)}{\log(N^4+N^2)}$, is it O($\log$ $n$)?

It would be appreciated if somebody could generalize the method of estimating big-O notation of fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The simplest way to see all this is to use *equivalents*:

- $\log(8n^3)=\log 8+3\log n\sim_\infty 3\log n$, so
  $$\frac{\log(8n^3)}{\log n}\sim_\infty\frac{3\log n}{\log n}=3,$$ hence it is $O(1)$.
- $n^3+7n+1\sim_\infty n^3 $, hence $\log(n^3+7n+1)\sim_\infty \log(n^3)=3\log n $,
- similarly $\log(n^4+n^2)\sim_\infty 4\log n$,

so $\;\dfrac{\log(n^3+7n+1)}{\log(n^4+n^2)}\sim_\infty \dfrac{3}{4}=O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for paying attention to the details. Now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
for any two polynomials
with complex coefficients,
$\dfrac{\log|P(n)|}{\log|Q(n)|}
=O(1)
$
as
$n \to \infty$.

You can go further
and show that
$\dfrac{\log|P(n)|}{\log|Q(n)|}
=\dfrac{u}{v}+o(1)
$
where $u$ and $v$
are, respectively,
the degrees of
$P$ and $Q$.